# Big o notation on both sides

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

Can someone explain what exactly means $o(o(f(x))) = o(f(x))$?
I do understand what little oh means by definition(fraction limit of two functions converges to zero) , but somehow i don't get the idea of Big o or little o on both sides.

Comment: It means that any function from l.h.s. belongs to r.h.s.

Comment: Can you please provide some example for clarification or show it in limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this expression in the following way: "any function $h(x)$ which is infinitely small compared to some other function $g(x)$, which, in turn, is infinitely small compared to function $f(x)$ (interpretation of left part of expression ends here) is itself infinitely small compared to $f(x)$".

Note, that "=" is not usual equality sign here, if you swap the left and right parts of this expression, it will not be correct any more.

UPDATE.

Well, in this particular example it IS possible to swap left and right parts of expression and it still will be correct. (Thanks to J.G. - author of another answer to this question).

In this example it is possible to interpret the expression as "set of functions described by the left part and the set of functions described by the right side are equal".

But I am quite sure I encountered expressions like $o(x^2) = o(x)$ meaning "our function is infinitesimal compared to $x^2$, so it is also infinitesimal compared to $x$"

Comment: So, whenever i see little oh it denotes the set of functions. Did i get it right?

Comment: @RamilAhmedov Yes.

Comment: Nevertheless, can I assert that o (o (f)) is a collection of infinitesimal functions f? Also, what happens if we change the first Little o to Big o. Does it violate the expression?

Comment: I think the answer to your first question is "no". Example: $h(x) = x; g(x) = x^2; f(x) = x^3$. In this case $h(x) = o(o(f(x))$ when $x -> \infinity$, but it is not infinitesimal.

Comment: Thank you. However, with provided example i can't prove that O(o(f)) = o(f). Also, can i actually decompose those sentences as follows:  h(x) = o(g(x)), g(x) = o(f(x)) and substitute g(x) with second sentence ?

Comment: @RamilAhmedov I do not know if there are some formal rules for processing such statements. May be there are, I just don't know. The expression with big O $O(o(f(x)) = o(f(x))$ means "our function $h(x)$ is limited compared to some other function $g(x)$ which is infinitesimal compared to $f(x)$ - so $h(x)$ is infinitesimal compared to $f(x)$.

Comment: Now i get it. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Since $o(f)$ is a set of functions, $o(o(f))$ is an [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation) for $\bigcup_{g\in o(f)}o(g)$. In particular, you can prove $h\in o(f) \iff\exists g\in o(f)(h\in o(g))$ using [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). In fact, you can choose $g=\sqrt{|fh|}$.